# The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, user-profile

i want change user profile (user name and photo). but it gives the error The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'. this is the code

```
onPressed: (){
                    var createUserWithEmailAndPassword = FirebaseAuth.instance.
                    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(

                      email: _email,
                       password: _password);
                    createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then((signedInUser){
                        var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
                        userUpdateInfo.displayName = _userName;
                        userUpdateInfo.photoUrl='https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Forangefootballclub.com%2Fen%2Farticles%2Fcristiano-ronaldo-says-will-fight-to-win-champions-league-for-juventus%2F&psig=AOvVaw3W_YulXC1W9I_Hpf0njprF&ust=1590379669136000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOj-3ZDQy-kCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ';
                       FirebaseAuth.instance.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo).
                       then((user){
                       FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
                       UserManagement().storeNewUser(signedInUser.user, context);
                       }).catchError((e){
                           print(e);
                       });
                       }).catchError((e){
                           print(e);
                       });


                       }).catchError((e){
                         print(e.toString());
                       });

                  },
```

please tell me a way to correct this code

Comment: Sorry there seemed to be some error in my answer is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseAuth.instance returns an instance of the FirebaseAuth class. You have to  get the current user and then updated the profile.

```
Firebase.auth.currentUser
```

This will return the current user

Replace this

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo)
```

With

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo)
```

As stated here in the documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#kotlin+ktx